# this in object is just clicked button

Tags: javascript, object, this

I'm not able to execute method from other method in object:

```
(() => {
  const wordCounter = {
    getText: function() {
       console.log(document.getElementById('textarea').innerHTML);
    },
    fireCounter: function() {
      console.log(this);
      this.getText();
    }
  }
  document.getElementById('button').addEventListener('click', wordCounter.fireCounter);
})();
```

in this example `this` is just a button which has eventListener. What I'm doing wrong? [demo](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/pQGERX?editors=1010)

> Uncaught TypeError: this.getText is not a function

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Event handlers will change the context of this, binding it to the button with the event listener on it. you need to re-bind this to the handling function:

```
 document.getElementById('button').addEventListener('click', wordCounter.fireCounter.bind(wordCounter));
```

I'd warn you that this is not an optimal solution, as you lose access to the clicked element (apart from `e.target`)

You can wrap the function call in a handler, to preserve all the info, like so:

```
(() => {
  const wordCounter = {
    text: '',
    getText: function() {
       console.log(document.getElementById('textarea').value); // <--
    },
    fireCounter: function() {
      console.log(this);
      this.getText();
    }
  }
  document.getElementById('button').addEventListener('click', () => {
    wordCounter.fireCounter();
  });
})();
```

Also, use `textarea.value`, rather than innerHTML

Comment: What's the optimal one?

Answer (score 0):

this is my solution:

```
(() => {
  const wordCounter = {
    text: '',
    getText: function() {
       console.log(document.getElementById('textarea').value);
    },
    fireCounter: function() {
      console.log(this);
      wordCounter.getText();
    }
  }
  document.getElementById('button').addEventListener('click', wordCounter.fireCounter);
})();
```

With "this" you try to call a function **outside** of "wordCounter" constant. So you have to call the constant instead of "this" followed by the function.

Answer (score 0):

The event handler will indeed change the context of your function but the real issue is that by taking the function out of its object, you also decouple it from its original context.

Example:

```js
var answer = {
  value: 42,
  get: function () {
    return this.value;
  }
};

console.log(
  answer.get()
);

var getAnswer = answer.get;

console.log(
  getAnswer()
);
```

Knowing that you then have two options:

1. don't take the function out of its object.

```js
button.addEventListener('click', function () {
  wordCounter.fireCounter();
});
```

2. make sure "standalone" `fireCounter` is still associated to its object with [bind](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_objects/Function/bind)

```js
button.addEventListener('click', wordCounter.fireCounter.bind(wordCounter));
```

Comment: I have chosen first option, refresh demo from my post.